# How is this pointer set up?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to learn how to use pointers in C and have come across the following code but am not sure what it means.

```
float xLeft [4] , *pLeft = xLeft ;
```

I know that `xLeft[4]` creates a an array of length 4, but I'm not sure what the second part `*pLeft = xLeft` does?

NB - the original question copied an incorrect version of the asterisk symbol `∗` from a textbook.  The code in the question has now been edited.

Comment: It declares a pointer called `pLeft` and assigns the address of `xLeft` to it, i.e., `pLeft` points to the beginning of `xLeft`.
You should get a good book on the fundamentals of C. Try "Modern C", which is available for free online: https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/modern-c/

Comment: `∗` is not a correct character for C source code.

Comment: Note the difference between `∗` and `*`, before you laugh at Eric.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer: The character in the question is Unicode U+2217, the “asterisk operator.” It is not an asterisk, which has the ASCII code 42, Unicode U+002A.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't notice that. Maybe OP copied this from some PDF and there is a formatting hiccup?
I'm not sure whether that was OPs question. I think they just don't know how pointers work.

Comment: Thanks v much!  Yes apologies `*` was intended rather than `∗`.  Does pLeft point to the whole of `xLeft` or just the beginning of it?

Answer (score 0):

`∗` (Unicode U+2217, the “asterisk operator”) is not a correct character for C source code. If it is corrected to an asterisk, then `float xLeft [4], *pLeft = xLeft ;` first declares `xLeft` to be an array of 4 `float`, then declares `pLeft` to be a pointer to `float` and initializes it using `xLeft`.

When an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof`, the operand of `unary &`, or as a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So `float … *pLeft = xLeft ;` initializes `pLeft` to point to the first element of `xLeft`.

Comment: Thanks!  so does pLeft point to the whole of the array xLeft or to just the beginning of it?

Comment: @MajorFighter: Is the eastern shore of the United States the start of the whole United States or just the eastern part of it? The start of a thing is also the start of the things inside the thing. The **type** of `pLeft` is pointer to `float`. When used in an expression `*pLeft` is a single `float`. The **value** of `pLeft` is the address of the first element in `xLeft`, and it is, when suitably converted, also the address of the entire array and of the first byte in the array.

Comment: Sure thing that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way,

```
float xLeft [4];
float *pLeft=xLeft;

say
xLeft[0]=1;
xLeft[1]=2;
xLeft[2]=3;
xLeft[3]=4;
```

Each memory location we will have a address and this address holds a value.

Let's assume our float array xLeft is located at address 0x0001. By that we mean the first element of xLeft, which is xLeft[0], has the address 0x0001 and a value 1. Similarly xLeft[1] has the address 0x0002 and a value 2, and so on, for the other elements of the array.

*pLeft is a pointer of type float, and when we assign *pLeft=xLeft, we just want our pointer to point or hold the address of xLeft. In our example *pLeft will be pointing to 0x0001.

If you try:

```
printf("The value of pLeft is: %f\n", *pLeft);
```

You should get the value at 0x0001 which is 1 in our case. With:

```
printf("The value of pLeft is: %p\n", pLeft);
```

Should return you the address 0x0001.